# SupportFragmentManager, popbackstack & screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a strange issue that is driving me mad!

**Scenario:**

I have `Activity` A as a launcher `Activity` and `Activity` B can be started through an `Intent` in `Activity A`

```
Activity A --> Activity B
```

Activity B has a initial `Fragment` call it `Fragment` C it is instantiated in `Activity` B like so:

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentC.TAG) == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .add(R.id.container,
                  FragmentC.newInstance(null), // optional bundle
                  FragmentC.TAG)
                 .commit();
}
```

In `Fragment` C I have a `RecyclerView` with an `OnClickListener` on the `ViewHolder` this calls back to the hosting `Activity` B through `Fragment` C.  At this point I start a `FragmentTransaction` (in `Activity` B) to replace the current `Fragment` C, call it `Fragment` D, and I add this transaction to the backstack:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .setCustomAnimations(
                  R.anim.fragment_slide_enter,
                  R.anim.fragment_slide_exit,
                  R.anim.fragment_slide_enter_pop,
                  R.anim.fragment_slide_exit_pop)
          .replace(R.id.container,
                        FragmentD.newInstance(bundle),
                        FragmentD.TAG)
          .addToBackStack(null)
          .commit();
```

So at the point I have `Activity` B with `Fragment` D with the transaction from `Fragment` C to `Fragment` D in the back stack, handling a back press like so :

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Navigation works correctly going forwards and backwards, from start `Actvity` A, through to `Activity` B --> `Fragment` D and back.

**Problem:**

However, if I am in `Fragment` D and rotate the screen, then `pop` the backstack to go to `Fragment` C (undo the transaction) I am presented with a blank `Fragment`.  What is more strange is that all of `Fragment` C's life cycle methods `OnCreate()`, `OnCreateView()`, `OnActivityCreated()` are called, and I have valid data/objects (checked through setting breakpoints).

Curiously however, if I do an `add` transaction when going from `Fragment` C --> `Fragment` D, obviously both are shown at once on top of each other, and I rotate the screen and press back and remove the transaction there is no issue, obviously not a solution, just an observation.

I have searched, yet everything I have read and tried does not work.  I have implemented something similar before, which worked fine yet I'm struggling here - any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

If the app goies into a pause state (left alone and screen goes off) and then woken up again, resumed, the Fragment appears as it should. I have no initialisation in `onResume` so I have no idea why this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

Ok, thanks for the suggestions but I have fixed the problem myself.

The Solution? Very simple and I'm kicking myself!

When popping the backstack I never included `getId()` of the `Fragment` to "pop" :

The code before was relying on the `FragmentActivity` to pop the backstack itself in `onBackPressed()`.  Indeed the documentation and method should take care of this:

```
/**
 * Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity
 * as appropriate.
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     if (!mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
      }
}
```

However it would seem that this does not work correctly when configuration changes have occurred and you want to pop the backstack to a previous transaction.  The code solution was to manually take of "popping" the back stack myself :

**Before:**

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**After (working solution):**

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(), 
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE));
    } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }
```

The documentation for `getId()` states:

```
/**
 * Return the unique identifier for the entry.  This is the only
 * representation of the entry that will persist across activity
 * instances.
 */
public int getId();
```

So basically the only way to successfully "pop" the backstack, after configuration changes have occured (hosting `Activity` has been destroyed and recreated) is to reference the `Fragments` unique `id`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem occured due to screen rotation.

**According to documentation,**  Your activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the device configuration changes, like when the user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load alternative resources (such as the layout)

In this case Your Activity B launch intial fragnment C again and all lifecycle methods are execute once again

**Solution**

1. You can restrict your activity in Portrait mode.
2. You should handle `onConfigurationChanged()` Method in your fragment and defined `setRetainInstance(true);` in onCreateView()

**public void setRetainInstance (boolean retain)
Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated:**

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen for landscape and portrait
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Individual `Fragments` and hosting `Activity` handle configuration changes  appropriately without issue.

Comment: For activity you can defined Configchanges attribute in manifest file. and for fragment you can override onConfigurationChanged() Method like i have explain in solution, Let me know if you are facing problem

Comment: @NishchalAndroid do have a point there. I have observed that, in case of fragments once the lifecycle methods will be called as is and then `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are called without calling `onResume()` and `onPause()` while rotating the screen. 
Log the lifecycle methods and see it for yourself. @MarkKeen

Comment: @Rolbin I have already checked (I mentioned break points in the original question). All lifecycle methods are called as they should (I handle configuration changes  appropriately), just nothing is shown almost like a headless Fragment ... I'm looking into possibility that the actual Fragment is attaching to the Activity, but a problem with the Fragment/Activity view hierarchy. The solutions provided do not work (I disagree with the reasoning for using them anyway)  - something more profound is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem previously. I have come up with solution which satisfy my requirement
use below code in menifest  for activity B

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

above line will not allow to destroy your activity so you don't have the problem of fragment destruction

Comment: Individual `Fragments` and hosting `Activity` handle configuration changes  appropriately - this solution is not appropriate for the problem I have.